# Help formulating node equations

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcWFRm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is to find the node voltage at e2 (I added the current lables and directions)  After getting it wrong, and seeing the correct answer I know that the correct equation must be

$$
\frac{e2-5}{3} + \frac{e2}{5} - 3 = 0
$$

However, I can't see how I would arrive at the above without having known the answer (i.e I'm bound to get the next one wrong too)

So this is how I tried to work it out.  I defined the currents into the node as positive, giving

$$
i1 - i2 + i3 = 0
$$
Where
$$
i1 = \frac{e2-e1}{R1} = \frac{e2-5}{3}
$$
$$
i2 = \frac{e2-e3}{R2} = \frac{e2}{5}
$$
$$
i3 = I = 3
$$
So
$$
\frac{e2-5}{3} -  \frac{e2}{5} + 3 = 0
$$

Which, with a couple of incorrect signs, gives the wrong answer.

What is wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is wrong with my logic?

Your 3rd equation is not consistent with the [passive sign convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention).

Since you've chosen \$i_1\$ to enter the \$e_1\$ terminal of \$R_1\$, the correct equation is, by the passive sign convention,

$$i_1 = \frac{e_1 - e_2}{R_1}$$

Note that one does not need to know in advance if \$e_1\$ is a higher potential than \$e_2\$.  It may be that, when the equations are solved, \$e_1 \lt e_2\$.

But that's irrelevant since, in that case, \$i_1\$ will be negative and thus, as desired, the current will be entering the more positive terminal of the resistor (a negative current to the right is a positive current to the left).

*Given* the reference polarities and reference directions chosen, the correct KCL equation for node 2 is

$$i_1 - i_2 + i_3 = \frac{5 - e_2}{3} - \frac{e_2}{5} + 3 = 0$$

which is equivalent to your 1st equation.

Answer (score 0):

Current goes from higher potential to lower. So as you assume \$i_1\$ goes from \$e_1\$ to \$e_2\$ 
then you actually assume \$e_1\$ is higher then  \$e_2\$ .So current equation is:

\$i_1 = \frac{e_2-e_1}{R_1}\$

\$i_1 = \frac{5-e_1}{3\Omega}\$

Comment: It's not a matter of which way the current flows, but of using consistent conventions throughout the computation.

Comment: I'm not telling 'it's matter which way the current flow' . I just try to explain why he have to write equation this way or you can say  'why the conventions is this way '